# HA-Proxy Intermittent 503

Tags: haproxy, http-status-code-503, intermittent

We have a integration with a vendor, where the requests will leave our haproxy and reachout the client via FW, for some reason we are having an intermittent 503 error, we did take a tcp dump at haproxy and found that after syn/ack with the client haproxy is not performing any TLS handshake, instead it is sending TCP keep alive and timing out, which will be back to normal after restarting the Haproxy container for couple of days, again it is throwing the same 503.
Tried below but no luck

a. increased timeout
b. increased connections
c. added resolver section to resolve to correct IP
d. removed/added health check

Haproxy version - 2.0

Can anyone help me with this??